# how to view C# modelstate errors in bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

**hello**, I use this template here: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/razor-page-crud-in-aspnet-core
and it's a very great tutorial. But I have a big problem:

How can I View modelstate errors OnPostCreateOrEditAsync ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmhUy.png)

Comment: In which method or exactly where you are getting the error? Share the exact code snippet where you are having the error and problem.

Comment: I added an image. My question is how to show the modelstate error in the view?

Comment: Its very hard to reproduce the error from the `image/screenshot`.  Please add your impacted code.

Comment: The project link and the screenshot you have shared is not same at all. Could you please explain along with your code what are you trying to implement and what are youb up to now?

Comment: this function is called when the form is submitted. I added data annotation validations to the model and it works fine. but if I want to add some custom validation such as the birthdate value can't be less than 18 years as in the picture. How can I show the modelstate error back to the user?

Comment: As its using `razor page` in that case you have to write a customer javascript function then need to bind it into `HTML`  tag.